# Can't login anymore

Tags: 12.10, tmp

In an attempt to free up disk space as I was 100% full and could not write to the disk anymore I ran

```
Sudo rm -rf /tmp
```

Seems like that was a rather stupid thing to do as I cannot login into my machine via the GUI. I can log in though when pressing Ctrl,  alt and f1 and access everything via the command line.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you recreate `/tmp` with the correct permissions, hopefully that will fix it:

```
sudo mkdir -p /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: When using mkdir /tmp it says already exists

Comment: Looks like the chaos worked, all working now...thank you